# Rolling hash overflow/negative result protection

Tags: java, string, algorithm, rabin-karp

This question is very similar to [rolling-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109624/need-help-in-understanding-rolling-hash-computation-in-constant-time-for-rabin-k), but there are some specifics regarding overflow/negative result which are still not clear to me.

I have as well checked out this Rabin-Karp [implementation](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html) and have issues with the line bellow:

```
txtHash = (txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q) % Q;
```

I understand that the following expression **might** give negative result:

```
txtHash - RM*txt.charAt(i-M)
```

*First question*:

- if we always add Q, a large prime, can this result with negative number due to overflow ?

  - If not, why not ? If yes, shouldn't this addition be done only if result is negative ?

*Second question*:

If, for a moment, we didn't care about negative numbers, would it be correct to write expression bellow ?

```
txtHash = (txtHash - RM*txt.charAt(i-M)) % Q;
```

*Third question*, this part confuses me most:

Lets assume that the overflow cannot happen when we add Q. Why is there left-most % Q operation over the leading digit ?

```
txtHash = (txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q ) % Q;
```

I have read the answer i have linked and according to the answer by Aneesh, and if i understood correctly expressions bellow should be similar:

```
hash = hash - ((5 % p)*(10^2 %p) %p)

txtHash = (txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q) % Q;
```

But i don't see why they are similar because in example with hash, % p is not calculated for previous hash value, however for txtHash we calculate % Q over the previous hash as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First question:
>
> if we always add Q, a large prime, can this result with negative number due to overflow ?
>           If not, why not ? If yes, shouldn't this addition be done only if result is negative ?

The prime number Q is usually chosen so that 2Q still does not overflow the type.

Now let's see.

- `txtHash` is from 0 to Q - 1.
- `RM*txt.charAt(i-M)` is large.
- `RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q` is from 0 to Q - 1.
- `txtHash - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q` is from -(Q - 1) to Q - 1.
- `txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q` is from 1 to 2Q - 1.

So, as long as 2Q - 1 does not overflow, the above expression is fine.

> Second question:
>
> If, for a moment, we didn't care about negative numbers, would it be correct to write expression bellow ?
>
> `txtHash = (txtHash - RM*txt.charAt(i-M)) % Q;`

Yeah, if the `% Q` always gave a result from 0 to Q-1 (as it does in Python for example), the above expression would be fine.

> Third question, this part confuses me most:
>
> Lets assume that the overflow cannot happen when we add Q. Why is there left-most % Q operation over the leading digit ?
>
> `txtHash = (txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q ) % Q;`

Suppose we remove the leftmost `% Q`.
Then let us estimate again:

- `txtHash` is from 0 to Q - 1.
- `RM*txt.charAt(i-M)` is large.
- How large? From 0 to (Q - 1) * CharCode.
- `txtHash - RM*txt.charAt(i-M)` is from -(Q - 1) * (CharCode - 1) to Q - 1.
- `txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-M)` is from -(Q - 1) * (CharCode - 2) to 2Q - 1.

Still possibly negative.
Not what we wanted.

Comment: Great answer! Since q is generated with 31 bits: BigInteger.probablePrime(31, new Random()).longValue(), this should satisfy the Q condition

Comment: If you don't mind, could you clarify a few more details? Shouldn't  upper bound for the last two expression include charCode as well ? How did we get -2 for the charcode in last expresion ?

Comment: @John we subtract the large number involving CharCode, so it contributes only to the lower bound.

Comment: You say that `RM*txt.charAt(i-M) % Q` is between 0 and Q-1. But if `RM*tx.charAt(i-M)` overflows we will get the wrong value even if we do `%Q` after that.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Yes, it can. But if it does, the whole question about subtraction is beside the point, since we can't just calculate in the given type anyway.